# Kratos Multiphysics build from source Python import

Tags: environment-variables, python-import

I cloned the Kratos Multiphysics [Kratos Multiphysics](https://github.com/KratosMultiphysics/Kratos) repository and created my own local branch. Then I compiled the unchanged code. This all worked without any problems. Now I try to import it into my Python (3.11) code and get the error "No module named 'KratosMultiphysics'". I have already added the location of the source code and the compiled code to `PATH`.

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\\...\\Kratos\\bin\\Release\\libs')

import KratosMultiphysics
```

When I print:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(sys.path)
```

The right directories are listed.
Any suggestions, what i'm dowing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only `PATH` has to be set right. `PYTHONPATH` is also neccessary.
For Windows command promt the following codelines are the key:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:/.../Kratos/bin/Release
set PATH=%PATH%;C:/.../Kratos/bin/Release/libs
```

A good discribtion can be found [here](https://github.com/KratosMultiphysics/Kratos/blob/master/INSTALL.md) in the section "Post Compilation".